# Валидатор букв

Tags: asp.net, регулярные-выражения, javascript, .net

Всем привет. задача:
буквы в строке должны быть либо английские либо русские, другие подчеркнуть красным, как обработать на javascript данную задачу, и какие варианты на сервере обработать .net (с#)
спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = "fhjk56++5про565";
re = /[^a-zа-я]+/ig;
repl = function (str){
    return "<span style = \"color:red\">"+str+"</span>";
};
alert(data.replace(re, repl));
```